# Why does function not run?

Tags: javascript

I have a div which has html code that displays a clock as the user plays the game, as shown below.

```
<td onclick="showClock()" id="clockSection">DAY 1</td>
```

I wanted to make it such that the time would update (e.g. from "Day 1" it turns into "Night 1" or "Day 2") would update every time the condition is met.

I made a function for this, `updateClock()` which works properly, as expected.

```
 function updateTime() {
  if (minutes >= 60) {
    minutes -= 60
    hours += 1
    updateTime()
  } else if (minutes >= 10) {
    minutesDisplay = minutes
  } else {
    minutesDisplay = "0" + minutes
  }
  if (hours >= 13) {
    hours -= 12
    if (dayHalf === "am") {
      dayHalf = "pm"
    } else {
      dayCount += 1
      dayHalf = "am"
      var clockDisplay = document.getElementById("clockSection")
      clockDisplay.innerHTML = displayTime
    }
  }
  if (hours > 6 && dayHalf === "pm") {
    timeEstimate = "Night"
    displayTime = timeEstimate + " " + dayCount
  } else if (hours < 7 && dayHalf === "am") {
    timeEstimate = "Night"
    displayTime = timeEstimate + " " + dayCount
  } else {
    timeEstimate = "Day"
    displayTime = timeEstimate + " " + dayCount
  }
  if (displayTime !== timeEstimate + " " + dayCount) {
    clock.innerHTML = displayTime
  }
  clock.innerHTML = displayTime
}
```

Unfortunately, when I wanted to call `updateClock()` from within my other function `beginGame()` (which starts the whole game, shown below), the entire beginGame() function did not run.

```
function beginGame(){
    updateTime()
...
    //the rest of my code, which when tested without the above updateTime() has NO PROBLEMS.
}
```

I tried running this and setting breakpoints in both functions, and turns out they both did not even run. However, when I took out the `updateTime()` from within `beginGame()` or if I took out the last `clock.innerHTML = displayTime` it could run properly (unfortunately the result was not what I had wanted). Why might this be so? I am quite sure I made some syntax error somewhere, but cannot spot it. Thanks.

Demo of full program is at tdat.byethost10.com. (The working version was supposed to begin the game upon typing "Begin", like at tdat.mygamesonline.org) Alternatively, here is a WORKING version of what's meant to happen (apologies for the messy HTML)

https://jsfiddle.net/hundotte/vb3je10p/1/

Comment: use jslint to improve the quality of your code http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: `"I am quite sure I made some syntax error somewhere, but cannot spot it."` - That's what your browser's debugging tools are for.  If the parser is encountering a syntax error, it will tell you on the JavaScript console.  Additionally, *we* certainly can't spot a syntax error in code you're only *describing* and not *showing*.

Comment: (Though if I were to *guess* about a syntax error, the fact that this code has *no* semicolons is probably a good place to start...)

Comment: Where is the `showClock` function? Are you calling `beginGame()` function somewhere? Because your call to `updateTime()` function seems to be inside that.

Comment: Could you post some other code regarding beginGame() and a little more of your HTML? I'd like to run a fiddle.

Comment: There are a lot of undeclared variables in your method. Can you tell us exactly which line is showing error in browser console?

Comment: If `updateTime()` works but not being called when you place it into `beginGame()` I see you have `... // the rest of my code` The source code that should be there could be the issue. If you have a syntax error in that source code then javascript will stop running meaning `beginGame()` is never called from that function. Please open your browser console to view any error reports.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have checked the browser console, AND my IDE console and no error is shown. The code is "running normally." If you would like the full code, it has been put (both the original working one and the broken one) in the question update.

Comment: Possible for you to recreate your problem with https://jsfiddle.net/ please. This will help everyone understand your issue and maybe find a solution for you. Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest you use `var` for all your variables. Maybe because you're not, some JavaScript error is creeping up. After all, without `var`, we won't know if the variable is being used or defined.

Comment: I DID use var for all my variables, but thanks for the reminder anyway.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I added `updateTime` to the end of your `beginGame` function (via the JSFiddle) and it seemed start after giving it the 'BEGIN' command. Is this not expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have finally solved the problem. It appears to be a slight spelling error, if you look at the JSFiddle you'll spot it. In the `beginGame()` function I put the id as "clock" instead of "clockDisplay". Thanks for trying, guys! I really appreciate it.